# Estimate pixels of proportional font in SVG or Java

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, svg, font-size

Is there an way to estimate the number of pixels used by a proportional font?
I am writing software that creates an image in SVG and transform that to PNG in Java. 
In this image I am using a text with a proportional font (size 16).
I can sometimes fit 26 characters in the picture and sometimes only 19.
This is because 'WWW' takes much more space as 'li1'.
How can I estimate the number of pixels a String needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [FontMetrics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) class - the stringWidth() method in particular.

If you have a graphics object `g` you are using for painting

```
g.getFontMetrics(f).stringWidth(message)
```